# queryselector onclick function gets rejected by DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Okay so here is the thing. I added a simple form like this:

```
        <form class="form form--character">
            <h1 class="title title--characters">Choose Players</h1>
            <div class="form--inputs">
            <input type="text" class="input input--players" placeholder="Player 1"><br>
            <input type="text" class="input input--players" placeholder="Player 2"><br>
            <input type="text" class="input input--players" placeholder="Player 3"><br>
            <input type="text" class="input input--players" placeholder="Player 4"><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn--add-characters">Add Player</button>
            <button class="btn btn--continue">Continue</button>
        </form>
```

The button called btn--add-players has the job to add another input into the div of inputs, which looks something like this:

```
window.onload =function(){
    var players=[];
    var playerInputCount=4; 
    var form = document.querySelector(".form--inputs");        
    document.querySelector(".btn--add-characters").onclick=function(){
        playerInputCount+=1;
        form.innerHTML = form.innerHTML + "<input type='text' class='input input--players' placeholder='Player " + playerInputCount + "'><br>";
    }
    
}
```

The problem now is.. when I click the button, the input gets added to the page, but within milliseconds the DOM seems to get resettet and the Input isnt there anymore.
I put a console log into the function to have a look if it still lands in the console after clicking.
It lands in the console but also within milliseconds the console log is away.
How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is inside a form, so when you click the button, it submits the form. Add `type="button"`.

```
<button class="btn btn--add-characters" type="button">Add Player</button>
```

Comment: You are a damn G. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

When  element is placed within a , its default action will be as a form submit button unless `type="button"` attribute is specified.

The additional elements created are dismissed because the button submits the . To prevent that from happening, add `type="button"` attribute for the button with "btn btn--add-characters" class, and it'll be okay.